# Dijkstra's algorithm shortest path

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, nearest-neighbor

I'm attempting to build a shortest path program and I have a question about the graph.  Are you supposed to draw the graph first??? How else would I define which nodes are neighbors???

Comment: This question is, at the very least, unclear.  I was going to downvote it, but I think you should a) reword the question and b) indicate if this is homework.

Comment: If you are really stuck and want to see a readable and well documented implementation of a graph, look through the source code for the Python library NetworkX: http://networkx.lanl.gov/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean programatically.

You define the adjacent nodes in your graph by the structure that you use to store the graph for your program to process it. There are several options: [adjacency matrix, adjacency lists and incidence matrix for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29#Representations).

Answer (score 0):

"Drawing" has nothing to do with this algorithm.

The graph is typically represented as a list of nodes (numbered 1..n) and a list of edges (ordered pairs source node # -> destination node #).
Other representations have been used such as a matrix with a column and row for each node.